# Hey Im getting an index out of bounds when entering 1 as char in Choice variable

Tags: java

**Code:**

```
System.out.println("Please choose an option");
Choice=user_input.next().charAt(0);
//entering 1 as char thats when it displayes "Do you want to open" then gives me index out of bonds error
if (Choice=='1'){
    System.out.println("Do you want to open a 'c'hecking Account or 's'aving account");
    Choice=user_input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if (Choice=='c'||Choice=='C'){
        System.out.println("You want to open a checking account");
        System.out.println("Please enter your name,Account number and balance");
```

**Output**

```
Please choose an option
1

Do you want to open a 'c'hecking Account or 's'aving account

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
 String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at BankOnlineSystem_Ayoub.main(BankOnlineSystem_Ayoub.java:18)
```

Comment: You typed 1, then <enter>, right? So the next item is 1, and then the line after that is just <enter> i.e. a blank line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Choice=user_input.next().charAt(0);
```

to

```
Choice=user_input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

to prevent your `user_input.nextLine()` from returning an empty String.

Comment: So its better i avoid using next function. Instead i always use nextLine right?

Comment: @chug next () is used to read a single String token from the current line. If you wish to read the entire line, you should prefer nextLine.